# Best way to display tabular data like the attached screenshot in Swift?

Tags: ios, user-interface, cocoa-touch, tabular

[image]

I am looking at the lower portion of this screenshot. If I had something similar to this in my design, what would be the best way to set this up in Swift?

I have looked into UITableView, but that doesn't seem to be quite what I need. Most of the tutorials & articles I've read regarding the UITableView only focus on 1 or 2 columns max, and don't really expand on how to go much beyond that.

I briefly considered just doing a bunch of statically placed labels, but realized that I will not always know exactly how many items are going to be in the table, so I need a more dynamic way of going about it.

Does anybody else have any advice on how I might go about achieving this sort of layout in Swift?

Comment: You might want to try CollectionView.

Comment: Try a custom table view cell (a UITableViewCell subclass) i.e, A cell with 4 labels and you can design a custom header as well

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways...

1. UITableViewCell subsclass. It's perfect for your purposue, and you can design it's contents following your needs. (No matter if 2, 3 or 4 columns)
2. Combination of StackView Vertical with StackView Horizontal inside. Each horizaontal view will contains one of your row.
3. Generate a HTML page and injec it in a SFSafariViewController or WebView.
4. Static content. A plenty of UILabel. One for each piece of information

In my opinion the best aproach is the UITableViewCell subsclass.